# TL431 With LM317 BMS

Tags: lm317, bms, tl431

[image]

I am trying to make a BMS circuit that I saw online using a TL431, but as I am new to electronics I am having some problems when using the TL431.

[image]

When I wanted to check the reference pin of the TL431, I placed R4 and then removed it after checking it's at 4.16 V when connected to the supply relative to the anode.

1. Shouldn't there be a R4 in this circuit so that the TL431 can change its resistance and thus make a stable voltage? In the picture it should be R4. If there isn't the voltage would always be the battery voltage.
2. I read that I should give a head room of 3 volts to the output of the LM317 but shouldn't that push the batteries above 4.2 and make it it dangerous?
3. If I put the R4 resistor I will have then a voltage difference between the battery and the TL431?

[![battery connections added with some tinkering][2]][2]

Comment: Where is your zener?

Comment: Also, proofread what you wrote and edit your post.

Comment: Please add the missing battery cell connections. It might be better to put the current limiting LM317 in front of the voltage limiting LM317. 1N914 cannot carry all the current if a cell is fully charged.

Comment: @MOSFET I meant the TL431 i fixed it

Comment: @Jens I added the battery and the connections its 2s 18650 do you mean to put the the current limit to the left of the voltage limit ? and in914 is supposed to handle .2 amps and my max is limited by .6 from lm317 shouldn't then be enough ?

Comment: Yes, put it to the left. Well, 600 mA from the supply will just burn out the 1N914, they are in series and so each of them carries the full current (for some hundred milliseconds :). Up to now I do not see any changes in the schematic.

Comment: You didn't fix it. You still have no zener in your circuit. And your problem statement is still not clear, both technically and grammatically.

Comment: @Jens thank you ,that seems to have fixed the problem its now showing the correct voltage 4.16 between each battery but why did switching the cv and cc regulators fix it ? Is it a problem in lt spice ?